# Плохая ли практика использовать prevSate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Плохая ли практика использовать prevSate?
И как можно переписать по-другому без prevState

```
  handleItemChange = id => e => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: {
            ...prevState.data ,
            [id]: e.target.value
        }
    }));
};
```

Comment: Относительно заголовка вопроса - это в большинстве случаев *хорошая* практика. Источник: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/816394376817635329/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fmedia%2Fd8a8ce2953f25b98611b1bea4f7600b6%3FpostId%3D1f5cfd6e55d1

Comment: Более развернуто: https://medium.com/@shopsifter/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1

Comment: По тому как Вы написали: чтобы сказать насколько это корректно надо видеть в контексте всего компонента. Может корректно может и нет. Нужно помнить что spread это shallow copy да и обработчик из двух стрелочек слегка смущает.

Comment: Без prevState можно мутировать this.state и вызывать самому forceUpdate руками. Можно вызвать следующий пересчет state в колбеке предыдущего. Передавать в setState функцию от prevState в таком случае куда удобнее и семантичнее.